# Text size changes on iPhones

Tags: html, css, sass

Good day.
I have such a question, I wrote an adaptive for the site, everything was fine. But when I launched the site on an iPhone, my main headings got smaller. Although in chrome on pc, font size is normal at all sizes. Below I am attaching screenshots.

Body styles have:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Tried 100% instead of "none". The result is the same

In chrome

[image]

In iPhone

[image]

Comment: font-family do not look the same. ;)

Comment: Wow. It is very strange. I didn't really notice this. But why is it so? The styles contain only one font with the woff and woff2 extensions. Maybe iPhones don't support these extensions on websites?

Comment: I also installed the svg format for fonts. I read that iPhones read them. The situation has not changed. I don't understand what the problem might be

Answer (score 2):

Try using `@media` queries. If the screen width goes below 450, change the font size:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450) {
  h1{
    font-size: <x>%;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already written all the settings for adaptive, for this screen, including the font size